# will it work on ie7-Background image

Tags: html, css, web

Will this code block work on IE7 and IE8??

```
    background: none #9C1F31 !important;
```

Will **background** property work on IE7 and IE8? I dont have IE7 to verify this code.

Please advise me.Thank you.

Comment: There's no need to ask easy questions like this: If you need to test this kind of thing you can use a service like http://browsershots.org/. They'll send you a screenshot of your site in any browser you like. It's free and easy. For more complex testing you can download an IE7 VM for free from http://modern.ie/ or use a service like http://browserstack.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It will work on IE7 and IE8.

**[You can refer more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)**

FYI: The value "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE.

Comment: thank you for ur reply, But  in your proof list ,ie 7 and ie8 are not supporting this propert.